# Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.facebook.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://myapp.herokuapp.com"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-javascript-sdk, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I get an unlimited amount of this message (like in a loop) and it breaks the website

Rails 4.0.0 (with Turbolinks)

**Error message**

> Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.facebook.com" from accessing
>   a frame with origin "http://app.herokuapp.com".  The frame requesting
>   access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a
>   protocol of "http". Protocols must match.

**Facebook.js.coffee**

```
fb_root = null
fb_events_bound = false

$ ->
  loadFacebookSDK()
  bindFacebookEvents() unless fb_events_bound

bindFacebookEvents = ->
  $(document)
    .on('page:fetch', saveFacebookRoot)
    .on('page:change', restoreFacebookRoot)
    .on('page:load', ->
      FB?.XFBML.parse()
    )
  fb_events_bound = true

saveFacebookRoot = ->
  fb_root = $('#fb-root').detach()

restoreFacebookRoot = ->
  if $('#fb-root').length > 0
    $('#fb-root').replaceWith fb_root
  else
    $('body').append fb_root

loadFacebookSDK = ->
  window.fbAsyncInit = initializeFacebookSDK
  $.getScript("//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js")

initializeFacebookSDK = ->
  FB.init
    channelUrl   : 'http://app.heroku.com/page/fbchannel'
    appId        : 'MY_ID_HERE'
    status       : true
    cookie       : true
    xfbml        : true
```

**PageController**

```
class PageController < ApplicationController
skip_before_action :authenticate_user!

def fbchannel
    cache_expire = 1.year
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "public"
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "max-age=#{cache_expire.to_i}"
    response.headers["Expires"] = (Time.now + cache_expire).strftime("%d %m %Y %H:%I:%S %Z")
    render :layout => false, :inline => "<script src='//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js'></script>"
  end
end
```

**FBlike** (helper)

```
def fblike(resource, layout = 'standard')

        content_tag(:div, "", class:"fb-like", data: {
            href: polymorphic_url(resource),
            width: "225",
            show_faces: false,
            stream: false,
            show_border: false,
            header: false,
            layout: layout

            }
        )
    end
```

Comment: Your channel URL must have the same protocol as the one used by Facebook: have you tried using https:// app.heroku.com/page/fbchannel for your channelUrl ?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old question, but it's still open- so In case you didn't see this answer already, Mademoiselle Geek is spot-on.  A quick double-check on my heroku app verifies that you can, in fact, just type https: instead of http: and it will accept an SSL connection automatically- no set up required.  The only thing you do have to set up is in your Facebook.js.coffee- this section..

```
initializeFacebookSDK = ->
  FB.init
    channelUrl   : 'http://app.heroku.com/page/fbchannel'
```

Change to..

```
initializeFacebookSDK = ->
  FB.init
    channelUrl   : 'https://app.heroku.com/page/fbchannel'
```

Then, depending on your operating system (I use linux) do a quick grep search (or search the text of files within a directory) for `http://app.heroku` and change it to https, just to be safe.